# necessary and sufficient conditions for weak convergence in $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

First, some definitions:

A sequence $[x_n]$ in a normed linear space $X$ is said to converge weakly to an
element $x$ if for every $\phi \in X^*,\,\,  \phi(x_n) \rightarrow \phi (x),$ (where$X^*$ is the conjugate space of $X$.)

As for $c_0$, let $c_0$ denote the space of all real sequences that converge to zero, with the norm $\| x\| = \sup_n |x(n)|.$

Now, I need to show that in order for a sequence $[x_n]$ to converge weakly to an element $x$ in the space $c_0$, it is necessary and sufficient that the sequence be bounded and that (for each $i$) we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n(i) =x(i).$

Here's my attempt at a proof:

First direction: assume that the sequence is weakly convergent, prove the boundedness and pointwise convergence:
We know that any weakly convergent sequence is bounded. Also, every continuous linear functional $\phi$ in $c_0$ can be written in the following form for some suitable point $\alpha$ in $l^1$. $$\phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \alpha(i) x(i)$$
Similarly, $$\phi_n (x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \alpha^\prime (i) x_n(i).$$ Now, due to weak convergence, we have $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi_n(x) = \phi(x) $. We pick $\alpha(i) = \alpha ^ \prime (i) = e(i) $, where $e(i)$ is the $i$th basis for $c_0$. Thus, we can conclude $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n(i) = x(i).$

Am I right so far? And if so, I'd appreciate any hint/help on the inverse direction of the proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the converse: Let $f \in c_0^*=\ell_1$. Then, there exists $z \in \ell_1$ such that
$$f(y)=\sum_{k =1}^\infty y(k) z(k), \ y \in c_0.$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Pick a sufficiently large integer $N$ such that
$$ \sum_{k>N} |z(k)| < ε/2M$$
where $M=\sup ||x_n||$. Since $x_n(k) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} x(k)$ for all $k$, we get that
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N |x_n(k)-x(k)| \ |z(k)|=0.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|f(x_n)-f(x)| &= |f(x_n-x)| \\
&= | \sum_{k=1}^\infty (x_n(k)-x(k)) z(k) | \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^N |x_n(k)-x(k)| \ |z(k)| + \sum_{k>N} |x_n(k)-x(k) \ |z(k)|.
\end{align*}
Conclude that $ \limsup |f(x_n)-f(x) | \leq ε$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first part is right.

Now suppose $(x_n)$ is bounded and $x_{ni} \to x_i$ for all $i$. Let $\phi$ be in the dual space so that we can write $\phi (x)=\sum \alpha_ix(i)$ with $\sum |\alpha_i| <\infty$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $n$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{\infty}  |\alpha _i| <\epsilon$. Now $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\alpha_i (x_{ni}-x_i)|=\sum\limits_{i=N}^{\infty} \alpha_i(x_{ni}-xi)|+\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{\infty} \alpha_i(x_{ni}-x_i)|$. Show that the second term does not exceed $2M\epsilon$ where $M=\sup |x_{ni}|$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is already answered,  let me offer another approach which works not only for $c_0$,  but also
for  $\ell ^p$, for
every $p\in (1, \infty )$, and  which also
highlights some important features of the problem.

**Lemma**.  Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $S\subseteq X^*$ be a *total set* (i.e., $S$ spans a dense subspace of $X$).   Then a
sequence $\{x_n\}_n\subseteq X$ converges to a given $x\in  X$ in the weak topology, if and only if

1. $\sup_{n\in {\mathbb N}}\|x_n\|<\infty $, and
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty }\sigma (x_n)=\sigma (x)$, for every $\sigma $ in $S$.

*Proof*.  Assuming weak convergence one gets (1) by Banach-Steinhauss and (2) is obvious.

Conversely, assuming (1) and
(2),  pick $\varphi $ in $X^*$,  and $\varepsilon >0$.   Next choose $\sigma $ in $\text{span}(S)$ such that $\|\sigma -\varphi \|<\varepsilon /3M$,  where $M$ is the
supremum in (2).

Observing that (2) implies that $\sigma (x_n)\to \sigma (x)$,   choose $n_0$ such that $|\sigma (x_n)-\sigma (x)|<\varepsilon /3$,  for all $n\geq n_0$.

For $n\geq n_0$ we then have
$$
  |\varphi (x_n)-\varphi (x)| \leq  $$$$ \leq
  |\varphi (x_n)-\sigma (x_n)| +  |\sigma (x_n)-\sigma (x)| + |\sigma (x)-\varphi (x)| \leq  $$$$ \leq
  \|\varphi -\sigma \Vert  \|x_n\| +  \frac\varepsilon 3 +   \|\varphi -\sigma \Vert  \|x\| \leq  $$$$ \leq
  \frac\varepsilon {3M} M +  \frac\varepsilon 3 +  \frac\varepsilon {3M} M = \varepsilon .
  \tag*{$\square$}
  $$

---

Back to the question,  let $X$ be either $c_0$ of $\ell ^p$,  with $p\in (1, \infty )$,  and let $S$ be the subset of $X^*$ consisting
of the functionals of the form
$$
  \sigma (x) = x(i),
  $$
where $i$ ranges in ${\mathbb N}$.  Then observe that condition (2) in the Lemma translates to
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty }x_n(i)=x(i), \quad\forall i\in {\mathbb N}.
  $$

To conclude the proof of the statement made in the original post, it is enough to observe that $\text{span}(S)$ is dense
in $X^*$.

We should remark that the last point in the sentence above  fails for $\ell ^1$ and for $\ell ^\infty $, and this is why these values of $p$ must be  excluded.